# Hodge star without a metric

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, duality-theorems, hodge-theory

The standard definition of the Hodge star is as follows: the Hodge dual of a differential $p$-form defined on an $n$ dimensional manifold $M$, $\alpha \in \Omega^p(M)$, is the unique form $\star \alpha \in \Omega^{(n-p)}(M)$ that satisfies
\begin{equation}
\beta \wedge \star \alpha = \langle \beta, \alpha \rangle \omega
\end{equation}
for any differential $p$-form $\beta$. Of course, implicit in this definition, there is a choice of metric on $M$, which induces an inner product on $p$-forms, as well as a choice of volume form $\omega$, although from what I gather this tends to be taken to be the volume form induced by the metric. The Hodge dual is then an isomorphism $\star \colon \Omega^p(M) \to \Omega^{n-p}(M)$, which reflects the fact that these spaces have the same dimension.

I noticed, however, that really the Hodge star is built out of two steps: the choice of a volume form gives you an isomorphism between $(n-p)$-forms and $p$-vector fields, and the choice of a metric gives an isomorphism between $p$-vector fields and $p$-forms.

I worked through the details in the case $p=1$. First, given a volume form $\omega$, we have what one could call a primitive Hodge star, $\ast \colon \Gamma(TM) \to \Omega^{n-1}(M)$ which is just an interior product: $\ast X = \iota_X \omega$. The other isomorphism is just the musical isomorphism $\sharp \colon \Omega^1(M) \to \Gamma(TM)$, which depends on the choice of a metric of course. I claim that the composition of the two is the Hodge star, namely, $\star \alpha = \ast \sharp \alpha = \iota_{\sharp \alpha} \omega$. And indeed, using the fact that the interior product is a derivation I can show this, since for any 1-form $\beta$
\begin{align}
\beta \wedge (\ast \sharp \alpha) &= \beta \wedge (\iota_{\sharp \alpha} \omega) \\
&=  (\iota_{\sharp \alpha} \beta) \wedge \omega - \iota_{\sharp \alpha}(\beta \wedge \omega) \\
& = \beta(\sharp \alpha) \omega \\
&= g^{-1}(\beta, \alpha) \omega
\end{align}
where $\beta \wedge \omega$ vanishes because it is a top form and I use $g^{-1}$ for the induced inner product on 1-forms. It also works nicely in coordinates, since if I introduce the $(n-1)$-forms $\omega_a = \iota_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}} \omega$, then
\begin{equation}
\ast X = \iota_X \omega = X^a \iota_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}} \omega = X^a \omega_a
\end{equation}

My question is whether this actually generalizes to higher dimensions (I am thinking of an isomorphism $\Gamma(\Lambda^p TM) \to \Omega^{n-p}(M)$ determined by a choice of volume form) and whether it might be useful to think of the bit of Hodge star determined only by a volume form in contexts in which a metric might not be readily available.

Comment: The musical isomorphism is determined by a metric, as you said, so I don't see in what way is this a "generalized" Hodge star.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't too clear but what I was referring to was the isomorphism that is given only by the volume form, which you then compose with the musical isomorphism (determined by the metric) to obtain the Hodge star. I have edited the question to reflect this.